# How to use Specification in custom methods in JPA Repository

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Let's say that I have this search repository method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e from Table t where t.a= :param1 and t.e= :param2")
Page<MyObject> search(Long param1, Long param2, Pageable pageable);
```

I want to apply a Specification into this method like follows :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e from Table t where t.a= :param1 and t.e= :param2")
Page<MyObject> search(Long param1, Long param2, Specification specification, Pageable pageable);
```

Is it possible to make it? Because I'm pretty sure that Specification can only applies on default Spring methods (`findAll`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is no. According JpaSpecificationExecutor you could use Specification object with the following methods:

```
findOne(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);
findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);
findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Sort sort);
count(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how to use specification in custom method in jpa really appreciate if some can answer this I need it very badly