# Spring data JPA: How to Sort on a jsonb field

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using **Specification** to query my table which contains a `jsonb` column. I want to sort on a field called 'type' in the jsonb column. (in postgresql the wanted result is like `ORDER BY content->>'type'`)

I've tried to use `JpaSort` like mentionned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66152164/2131117) but it is not working !

Another solution which worked for me is to use `@Formula` but I've to use it for all my json nested fields. Not elegant as solution. I prefer use separate columns in this case.

```java
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //this works but not wanted
    //@Formula("content->>'type'")
    //private String type;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> content;
}
```

```java
myEntityRepository.findAll(hasIdSpecification(5), new new OffsetPageRequest(0, 10, sort()));
```

And `sort()` is

```
JpaSort.unsafe(Direction.ASC, "jsonb_array_elements_text(content, 'type')")
```

I'm getting the following error

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'jsonb' found for type 'MyEntity'!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331)
```

`QueryUtils.toJpaOrder` will split the postgresql function on the '_' character and hence will look for `'jsonb'` field in my entity.

Is there a way to escape the underscore '_' ? Or maybe suggest me another solution

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is **`NO`**.

For inherited main methods like `.findAll(Sort sort)`, **you can only use object properties to define our sort,** otherwise you will get `No property '?' found for type '?'!` error!

When we use JPQL for a query definition, then *`Spring Data`* can handle sorting without any problem — all we have to do is add a method parameter of type Sort in `MyEntityRepository` file.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM MyEntity e")
List<MyEntity> findAllForJSON(Sort sort);
```

`-- OR --`

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM MyEntity e")
Page<MyEntity> findAllForJSON(Pageable pageable);
```

Accordingly, you need to mix `@Query` and `Specification` to get exactly what you want to do, [but you can't mix `@Query` and `Specification`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58231771/how-to-use-specification-in-custom-methods-in-jpa-repository)

**Consequently**; You need a special method to use the [**`jsonb_array_elements_text`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function, but we cannot use this method with the specification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you can see in my question I'm using **Specification** for querying my database. I want a solution with **Specification** not repository methods.

Comment: I updated my answer to be clear. @flywell